# Resolving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException while using ArrayList

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java development field and still i am a learner of Java Programming. I wanted to see the output for the Support Vector Machine classifier on netbeans IDE. So i copied this attached piece of code and tried to run by using all the other required class and main method as well but i am getting `Number format exception` when i give a file containing input like 23,25,26,27 during the call of the method `loadBinaryProblem()` in main method and if i remove all the commas and replaced them with space ex: 23 25 26 27 then i am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception instead of it. So anybody can help to get the output properly without any error.

```
package svmlearn;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Class representing an optimization problem (a data setting);
 * taken from liblinear; "bias" excluded
 * @author miafranc
 *
 */
public class Problem {
        /** The number of training data */
        public int l;
        /** The number of features (including the bias feature if bias &gt;= 0) */
        public int n;
        /** Array containing the target values */
        public int[] y;
        /** Map of categories to allow various ID's to identify classes with. */
        public CategoryMap<Integer> catmap;
        /** Array of sparse feature nodes */
        public FeatureNode[][] x;
        public Problem() {
                l = 0;
                n = 0;
                catmap = new CategoryMap<Integer>();
        }
        /**
         * Loads a binary problem from file, i.e. having 2 classes.
         * @param filename The filename containing the problem in LibSVM format.
         */
        public void loadBinaryProblem(String filename) {
                String row;
                ArrayList<Integer> classes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                ArrayList<FeatureNode []> examples = new ArrayList<FeatureNode []>();
                try {
                        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
                        while ((row = r.readLine()) != null) {
                                String [] elems = row.split(" ");
                                //Category:
                                Integer cat = Integer.parseInt(elems[0]);
                                catmap.addCategory(cat);
                                if (catmap.size() > 2) {
                                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("only 2 classes allowed!");
                                }
                                classes.add(catmap.getNewCategoryOf(cat));
                                //Index/value pairs:
                                examples.add(parseRow(elems));
                        }
                        x = new FeatureNode[examples.size()][];
                        y = new int[examples.size()];
                        for (int i=0; i<examples.size(); i++) {
                                x[i] = examples.get(i);
                                y[i] = 2*classes.get(i)-1; //0,1 => -1,1
                        }
                        l = examples.size();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                }
        }
        /**
         * Parses a row from a LibSVM format file.
         * @param row The already split row on spaces.
         * @return The corresponding FeatureNode.
         */
        public FeatureNode [] parseRow(String [] row) {
                FeatureNode [] example = new FeatureNode[row.length-1];
                int maxindex = 0;
                for (int i=1; i<row.length; i++) {
                        String [] iv = row[i].split(":");
                        int index = Integer.parseInt(iv[0]);
                        if (index <= maxindex) {
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException("indices must be in increasing order!");
                        }
                        maxindex = index;
                        double value = Double.parseDouble(iv[1]);
                        example[i-1] = new FeatureNode(index, value);
                }
                if (n < maxindex)
                        n = maxindex;
                return example;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried debugging using breakpoint? It will help especially when dealing with those kind of issue. You have a lengthy code there.

Comment: Seeing the `split` methods, I am assuming that your input must be a mix of numbers seperated by white spaces and colons. Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Actually i am giving .csv file as an input to the function. this file contains comma separated variables just like 23,25,26 etc... here there is no white space or colon. i am initially trying with the file consists of complete integers

Answer (score 4):

i guess NumberformatExceptions comes from:

```
String [] elems = row.split(" "); //nothing done by "23,25,26,27"
//Category:
Integer cat = Integer.parseInt(elems[0]); //you are trying to parse "23,25,26,27"
```

ArrayIndexOutOfBound comes from:

```
String [] iv = row[i].split(":");//nothing done
...
double value = Double.parseDouble(iv[1]);//1 is out of bound
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. i am getting the error as java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "23,25,26,27" for the above attached program.  But if i change the statement String [] elems = row.split(" "); into String [] elems = row.split(","); i am getting the error as java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 please help me where to modify the code.

Comment: if you change to split(","), you still get the second error. You try to split(":") ans since you dont have any ":" in your strings, you will get this error. try another input-string: "12 32:2.4 33:2.5" this should run without errors. 12 will be the category, 32->2.4 index->value, 33->2.5 index->value

Comment: If i am trying as per as your suggestion i am getting error as below Loaded.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Training...
* at svmlearn.Completesvm.simpleSMO(Completesvm.java:98)
 at svmlearn.Completesvm.svmTrain(Completesvm.java:60)
 at svmlearn.Completesvm.svmTrain(Completesvm.java:49)
 at svmlearn.Completesvm.main(Completesvm.java:303)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Here i am entering a link for the program which contains the lines in which the compiler is showing the error https://code.google.com/p/svmlearn/source/browse/trunk/svmlearn/src/svmlearn/SVM.java?r=6#94 and i am entering the link for main() method as well https://code.google.com/p/svmlearn/source/browse/trunk/svmlearn/src/Main.java?r=6 and in the 1st link there is slight changes in the line numbers, here 98 means 94, 60 means 45, 49 means 34. please help in solving my problem

Comment: yes, but this is an error in other classes:"(Completesvm.java:98)" i mean this peace of code, that you posted in the question would run without errors. I dont actually know, what this program does. The problem is probably that you load wrong data or something, but this error occurs not in this peace of code, its somewhere else in program. Hmm actually, if it should be some kind of optimization problem, maybe you need some variable indexes, so you can set the values, try this input string: "0 0:1.0". Do you actually split by " " or ","? edit: ok, ill look at it

Comment: I have attached a link for other related program in which its showing error in my previous comment and i meant to split by ",".

Comment: try to parse this file:http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary/a1a it should work with this program, cahnge the split to " ". I think the problem is not the program, its your input string. The program expects the input in some format

Comment: just downloaded the project and executed with the file i posted before and it works:Loaded.
Training...
................................ just like i said before, download the project, take 2 files in the right format and it will work

Comment: I am trying to access the mentioned file to give as input to the program but currently the mentioned file is not available online or the server is off currently